# Rewrite shell script without whitespace

Tags: bash, shell, pam

Is it possible to write a shell script like that without using spaces, tabs or newlines:

```
/path/to/foo; test $? -ne 6
```

The script runs another program and fails iff its return code is 6.

### Background

I use this together within `pam_exec.so` and another program that controls access to a system. It does not relate to security, and I want to ensure access to the system if something about that other script fails (other than rc 6). The other program is a bit brittle, may break for various reasons, or simply be unavailable due to a messed up installation. I currently use a wrapper script, but that again needs to be deployed and i need to ensure that deployment of that script is consistent with the pam configuration. I would prefer a self-contained portable solution within the pam configuration.

Unfortunately 1) `pam_exec.so` doesn't care for the return code of the program it calls, and 2) the pam.d config parser does not care for quotes, it just splits arguments by `" \n\t"`, so I cannot use

```
... pam_exec.so /bin/bash -c "/bath/to/foo; test$? -ne 6"
```

I am curious if there is a way to reformulate that such that it does not need spaces and can be used here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an arithmetic statement, which requires less whitespace during parsing.

```
bash -c '/path/to/foo;(($?!=6))'
```

Comment: Simple... great :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dealing with whitespace I would create a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/local/sbin/foo-wrapper
/bath/to/foo
test $? -ne 6
```

pam config:

```
... pam_exec.so /usr/local/sbin/foo-wrapper
```

Comment: I currently use a wrapper script, but that again needs to be deployed and i need to ensure that deployment of that script is consistent with the pam configuration. I would prefer a self-contained portable solution within the pam configuration.

Comment: To be honest, a `bash -c` call that relies on no spaces in the command will break at least at the next update, when a co-worker touches it. And he will hate you.